# TCSH Change Shell Highlight Color

Tags: unix, colors, terminal, tcsh

I am looking to add color to my tcsh prompt.

I have gotten everything off the internet so far, the background and foreground color. If I want to highlight say the output of the command 'pwd' to copy into my next command, is there anyway to change the highlighting color to another color aside from the default black black color? I cannot find anything online other than just changing the background and foreground color...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "highlight the output of the command 'pwd' to copy into my next command"? You mean you want to highlight the output of the `pwd` command? What does "copy into my next command" mean and how is it related to highlighting?

Comment: Yeah so for example if I type in 'pwd' then the response to that is my current working directory (foo/bar/some/thing/else). In order to copy something, you need to highlight it. Right now the highlighting color is black, is there any way to change it to yellow as an example?

Comment: Right, you mean how to change the colours of the selected text? That is a setting in the terminal emulator, not the shell. The shell doesn't know anything about text selection.

Comment: Ahh okay got it. Thanks for that clarification! Would you happen to know how to access that and if I am able to change that? I am looking into it right now but cannot find anything yet...

Comment: It depends on which terminal emulator you're using.

Comment: when I type 'echo $TERM' i get back 'xterm'. Does that help??